# What is the most optimum way to get best results out of protein shakes?

Tags: bodybuilding, biceps

I am 31 years old, here is my 4 days plan:

1. Tuesday: Biceps only - 1 hour
2. Wednesday: Triceps only - 1 hour
3. Thursday: Chest only - 1 hour
4. Friday: Shoulder + Back - 1 + 1 hours
5. Saturday+Sunday+Monday: No exercise, just posing (contracting muscles w/o weights) 10 mins a day

In above workout there is little warm up in beginning and warm down in end. Immediately after exercise I take 1 egg with cold water. After that one glass milk with oats+Poha, followed by normal routine food, in night I take two glucose biscuits and 1 glass milk.

**I started this in August 2014 - till now. In beginning by biceps were 13.8, now they are 14.5(after flexing), weight was 80Kilos and now it is 77Kilos.**

My target is 16 inches biceps (after flexing).

1. Keeping this routine when I can expect reaching my target?
2. Should I purchase and protein shake in my routine to reach the target or that can be achieved without it?
3. **What is the most optimum way to get best results out of protein shakes?**

Comment: Drink them with your mouth.

Comment: BTW...if your goal is big arms, train your triceps slightly more than biceps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:**

Make sure you are using compound movements in addition to isolation exercises.  This puts you in the best position to make use of the protein you consume.  Squats, pull ups, deadlifts, bench press and military press.  All of these things help increase your body's demand from protein.

*Never* neglect your legs.  They aren't glamorous, but they help complete the look.

**Step 2:**

Spread your protein intake throughout the day.  The majority of your protein you want from real food.  Lean meats, fruits and veggies should be the foundation of any bodybuilder's menu.

Save the protein shake for training:

- Before training: 15g protein with creatine, quick carbs (i.e. glucose or sugar) and some caffeine
- During training: 15g protein with BCAAs and quick carbs (most protein shakes include BCAAs so you don't have to worry too much about it)
- After training: 15g-20g protein, and a lower amount of quick carbs.

Comment: Step1 - do you want me to squat on biceps days. What I dont understan dis, if I do compound exercise that it never be bicep days, chest days, tricep days, shoulder+back days or legs days. It will always be mix exercise. Please reply if got it wrong the STEP1.

Comment: What I'm strongly suggesting is that you keep compound movements in with the rest of your work.  A whole day devoted to biceps seems a bit much to me, particularly since you can have a leg day, an arm day (triceps and biceps), shoulder and back day, etc.  Biceps make up 2/3 the mass of your upper arms.  It only makes sense that the work should be scaled accordingly.

Comment: Please quote an example, of compound exercise or share link. I can (want to )spend only 1.5 hour a day. Apart from that I have 8 hours in office and other routine work at home.

Comment: Completely doable.  Here's one example of a bodybuilding focused program with compound lifts: http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/beginner-to-advanced-bodybuilder-in-12-weeks.html  Typical time in the gym will be roughly 1 hour give or take 15 minutes.

Comment: The first workout in that link you provided has minimum 42 minutes of rest periods, and 24 sets. It's going to take more than an hour.

Comment: You can manage time by super-setting.  The last 4 exercises can be done back to back in one set.  Rest 2 minutes in between.  That collapses 12 sets into 3 super-sets.  That also brings total rest time down to about 24 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Drink shakes whenever your organism is depleted of amino acids in the blood stream.

1. «Fast protein» (e. g. whey) in the morning and immediately after workout.  Some people consume a half portion before the workout, but it can make you want to puke during harder exercises.
2. «Slow protein» (e. g. casein or a «protein matrix» mix) 30 mins before lunch and before going to bed.

The idea is to create constant surplus of amino acids so that your muscles can draw them from the bloodstream any moment they need them.

Comment: "amino acids" are responsible for larger muscles?? how to know that level is depleted?? "half portion" of what, is it half tablespoon, with juice or milk and how much??

Comment: Half portion of what is said on your protein can.  Typically 1 scoop = 1 portion.  "Amino acids" are building blocks of muscle fiber.

Answer (score 0):

> Keeping this routine when I can expect reaching my target?

Consider dumping your whole routine and sticking with something like [Starting Strength](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/The_Starting_Strength_Novice/Beginner_Programs) or [Strong Lifts 5x5](http://stronglifts.com/5x5/). You will end up bigger and stronger. I just measured my upper arm for this question and am sitting at 15". I've never done a bicep curl in over five years but can do muscle ups, pullups with plates hanging off, and other no-kidding strength training stuff.

> Should I purchase and protein shake in my routine to reach the target
>   or that can be achieved without it?

Your routine will not target your largest muscles, and is unbalanced. As such you actually have lower protein requirements than someone doing more serious strength training. More broadly, protein supplements are for those who don't have enough protein in their diet otherwise. You'd be better off using real food sources (meat, eggs, etc) because they are slower to digest and contain other essentials (vitamins, creatine, etc). But high quality real-food protein is expensive and tough to get constantly, so people will pad their daily values with protein powders.

> What is the most optimum way to get best results out of protein
>   shakes?

Optimally the best results would probably be to not even need them because you have such a great diet of fresh whole food. I'm guessing you're talking about whey protein, so I guess you could say optimal would be an hour or so after lifting with a bit of carbohydrate.

The reality though is that with your routine and protein shakes, you'd be much better off doing a real strength training program and trying to eat more real food.

Comment: can you send link/blog on it **Starting Strength or Strong Lifts 5x5**

Comment: @paul , updated my answer with links

Answer (score 0):

I would keep your protein shakes to post workout only. Whey protein is highly insulinogenic. So it is the ideal choice to drink after you train, but you don't need to drink shakes during the course of the day. Stick to eating whole foods, Meat, eggs, yogurt, beans, nuts, etc. Whole foods will keep you fuller and keep your blood sugar balanced throughout the day.

If you are really concerned about staying anabolic throughout the day, buy some BCAA's (branched chain amino acids, valine, leucine and isoleucine) and take 5 grams with water every couple of hours. Definitely take 5 grams pre, peri and post workout as well.

I hope that helps.

Mike